# Como manter o layout dos componentes criados pelo WindowBuilder no eclipse após a compilação?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe

Criei um JFrame utilizando o plugin WindowBuilder do Eclipse. Foi definido espaçamentos, tamanhos e padrões. Entretanto ao compilar o projeto os padrões são perdidos. Abaixo as 2 fotos para comparação.

Aqui é o Preview do JFrame.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

JFrame após compilação.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de manter o layout e padrões da primeira imagem. Alguém poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione o código a seguir dentro do seu `main()`:

```
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Por exemplo deixando assim:

```
public class Tela extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Tela frame = new Tela();
                    frame.setVisible(true); 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Tela() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Adicionando o código em questão, você está aplicando o *Look and Feel* do seu sistema, caso contrário a aplicação escolherá o padrão que é o Metal.

> CrossPlatformLookAndFeel—this is the "Java L&F" (also called "Metal") that looks the same on all platforms. It is part of the Java API (javax.swing.plaf.metal) and is the default that will be used if you do nothing in your code to set a different L&F.

Fonte: [The Java Tutorials - How to Set the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#programmatic)

Comment: Obrigado @Math. Resolveu em partes meu problema. O *look and feel* dos componentes foram mudados. Entretanto o problema dos espaçamentos ainda continua. :/

Comment: Espaçamento entre os componentes? Poderia [edit] sua pergunta e colocar um print pra entender como que fica? Pois não consigo ver essa diferença rodando um projeto meu.

Comment: Dê uma olhada na figura 1, os botões abaixo "limpar", "salvar" e "salvar e sair" estão alinhados, já na figura 2 após a compilação esses espaçamentos são perdidos.

Comment: Ah sim, agora eu percebi isso. Qual Layout Manager está utilizando no rodapé? Por exemplo, BorderLayout, GridBagLayout, MigLayout, etc..

Comment: Resolvi. Era só prestar um pouco mais de atenção nas grid! Obrigado!